# How do I send an email to the administrator users when a specific link is clicked?

Tags: 7, emails

I'm working on a new site built with Drupal 6, and I have to program a specific action on the node pages.
I have a page that shows the product information for users. Following the information, I have a button labeled "order now"; when this button is clicked, two scenarios are possible:

1. if the user is not logged in, he is redirect to the login form
2. if the user is logged in, an e-mail is sent to the administrator with the current product information and the information of the user who clicked the button

Answer (score 2):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) Module can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module, or simply try the [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) installation profile.

It is a complete commerce solution which is highly integrated with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, so you can easily define what you described in your question.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but i don't like to install a hole complex module for that because it's not an e-commerce web site , i'd like a very simple hook or cutom module to run this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a submit callback for the button and check the current user with `global $user;`. Just add `$form['button']['#submit'] = array('mymodule_submit_callback');` to the button's array and use the callback to do your work.

```
function mymodule_submit_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 0) {
    // Send the user to the login page if user is anonymous.
    drupal_goto('user');
  }
  else {
    drupal_mail(); // Send an email to the administrator.
  }
}
```

So, here you have access to the user that clicked the button as well as any form data in `$form_state['values']`. Check out the [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) API reference for information on how use this function to send mail.

Alternatively, if you want to just provide a link you could also just use a menu callback.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['path/to/callback/%user'] = array(
    'title' => t('Send mail'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_mail_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_mail_callback($user) {
  // Check if this is an anonymous user and redirect if necessary.
  if ($user->uid == 0) {
    drupal_goto('user');
  }
  else {
    drupal_mail(); // Etc.
  }
}
```

Then, the link on the node form can be done like this

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Ensure this is the form you want with a conditional.
  global $user;
  // Add your "Order now" link to the form, linking to your menu callback.
  $form['mail_link'] = array('#value' => l(t('Order now'), 'path/to/callback/' . $user->uid));
  return $form;
}
```

Alternatively, you could disclude the user ID from the menu callback path and just get the `global $user` variable from within the menu callback itself.